# what would the components needed and how do I transfer this query to be used in ODI?

Tags: sql, oracle, mapping, oracle-data-integrator

I am quite new with ODI (Oracle Data Integrator), learn how to do basic mapping and with filter, expression from source -> target tables but this time I have such query that I should transform it into mapping in Oracle.

```
WITH OUTER_QRY AS
(
SELECT T1.DATA_ID, T1.EMP_ID, T1.EMP_STORE, T1.HIRED_DATE, T1.EMP_STATUS
FROM L_EMPLOYEES T1
WHERE 1=1
  AND T1.DATA_CREATE_DATE_TIME IN (SELECT  MAX(DATA_CREATE_DATE_TIME) 
                            FROM L_EMPLOYEES T2 
                            WHERE T2.EMP_ID = T1.EMP_ID 
                              AND T2.EMP_STORE = T1.EMP_STORE
                              AND T2.HIRED_DATE = T1.HIRED_DATE
                            )
  AND T1.EMP_STATUS = 'REMOVED'
  AND T1.EMP_ID = '123456789' -- used to query smaller data as example
)
SELECT EMP_ID, EMP_STORE, HIRED_DATE, FILED_DATE
FROM L_EMPLOYEES LE
WHERE 1=1
  and (LE.EMP_ID, LE.EMP_STORE, LE.HIRED_DATE) NOT IN (SELECT EMP_ID, EMP_STORE, HIRED_DATE FROM OUTER_QRY)
  AND LE.EMP_STATUS = 'ACTIVE'
  AND LE.EMP_ID = '123456789' -- used to query smaller data as example
group by EMP_ID, EMP_STORE, HIRED_DATE, FILED_DATE
ORDER BY HIRED_DATE 
;
```

To start with, since we are using the same table two times and there is an outer query, I thought I can do something like joining the two tables then filter them with this as condition.

So the structure looked like two source table (same table) joined together with a join component -> filter -> expression -> target table

And below is what's in the first filter condition, which does give me exact solution as if I make query only for outer query

```
1=1
  AND L_EMPLOYEES_T1.DATA_CREATE_DATE_TIME IN (SELECT  MAX(L_EMPLOYEES_T2.DATA_CREATE_DATE_TIME) 
                            FROM L_EMPLOYEES_T1
                            WHERE L_EMPLOYEES_T2.EMP_ID = L_EMPLOYEES_T1.EMP_ID 
                              AND L_EMPLOYEES_T2.EMP_STORE = L_EMPLOYEES_T1.EMP_STORE
                              AND L_EMPLOYEES_T2.HIRED_DATE = L_EMPLOYEES_T1.HIRED_DATE
                            )
  AND L_EMPLOYEES_T1.EMP_STATUS = 'REMOVED'
  AND L_EMPLOYEES_T1.EMP_ID = '123456789' -- used to query smaller data as example
```

I thought in this way, I can plug in another filter between expression and target table so the expression can be used as outer query

```
1=1
  and (L_EMPLOYEES_T1.EMP_ID, L_EMPLOYEES_T1.EMP_STORE, L_EMPLOYEES_T1.HIRED_DATE) NOT IN (SELECT EMP_ID, EMP_STORE, HIRED_DATE FROM EXPRESSION)
  AND L_EMPLOYEES_T1.EMP_STATUS = 'ACTIVE'
  AND L_EMPLOYEES_T1.EMP_ID = '123456789' -- used to query smaller data as example
```

But the above doesn't work that expression isn't a table.
I tried reading through the document of subquery filter component which I am not sure if it's the correct one to use but played around with it a bit and couldn't get it to work too because either no table found or invalid operation.

Does anyone has any suggestions / advise what should be the correct way to do this kind of mapping?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The subquery filter component would indeed be a solution for you.
In the Properties pane, go on the Condition tab and enter a Subquery Filter Condition like this one :

```
    NOT IN (
        SELECT EMP_ID, EMP_STORE, HIRED_DATE FROM FROM L_EMPLOYEES T1
            WHERE 1=1
            AND T1.DATA_CREATE_DATE_TIME IN (SELECT  MAX(DATA_CREATE_DATE_TIME) 
                            FROM L_EMPLOYEES T2 
                            WHERE T2.EMP_ID = T1.EMP_ID 
                              AND T2.EMP_STORE = T1.EMP_STORE
                              AND T2.HIRED_DATE = T1.HIRED_DATE
                            )
            AND T1.EMP_STATUS = 'REMOVED'
    )
```

another way to do it is to use the sql override method :

- Drag and drop your `L_EMPLOYEES` datastore only once on the canvas and connect it to your target.
- Go on the Physical tab and click the source datastore
- In the Properties pane, go on the Extract Options tab
- Set your entire query (as posted in your question above) as the value for CUSTOM_TEMPLATE option

There is an example in this blog post : https://blogs.oracle.com/dataintegration/odi-12c-sessionizing-data-with-matchrecognize-and-sql-override

This method should not be abused as it makes it less visual in ODI so harder to maintain. But it is a great tool to use when the query is complex as this is the case here.